# Making rest service with a bidirectional object

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

Situation: I'm trying to get all persons as a rest service. But the problem is that the class Person has persons on his own(Friends). So I'm getting an infinite long json, cause of the friends connection ...

The result were I'm aiming for:

```
 `{"naam":"Lance","voornaam":"ADAM","email":"Adam.Lance@msn.com","password":"fxSg1vSa2zzqHxuTCrDSbtp9ITlHf9ALSnS/ENFXfAA=$7vSVqz5nHZ7cEA4u6OiTBDw+CGaOJkhun4YuievZCKc=","username":"adam","status":"online","posts":[{"message":"Ik heb mijn eerste auto gekocht.","mood":"trots","when":1494603638834},"role":"ADMIN","friends":[{"username":"adamsFriend1"},{"username":"adamsFriend2"}]
```

So that I'm only getting the usernames of those friends. if this is not possible is there a way to exceclude those friends?

The Restcontroller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UsersRestController {

private final Service service;

public UsersRestController(@Autowired Service service) {
    this.service = service;

}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Person> getUsers() {
    return service.getAllPersons();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Person getUser(@PathVariable String id) {
    return service.getPerson(id);
}

}
```

the Person class:

```
    @Entity
public class Person {

private String naam, voornaam, email, password;

@Id
private String username;
private String status;

@ManyToMany
private Collection<Person> vrienden;

@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<Post> posts;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Role role;

public Person(String naam, String voornaam, String email, String password, String username) {
    setNaam(naam);
    setEmail(email);
    setStatus("online");
    setVoornaam(voornaam);
    setPassword(password);
    setUsername(username);
    vrienden = new HashSet<>();
    posts = new HashSet<>();
    role = Role.USER;
}

public static void addFriend(Person a, Person b) {
    a.addFriend(b);
    b.addFriend(a);
}

private void addFriend(Person b) {
    this.vrienden.add(b);
}

public static void deleteFriend(Person a, Person b) {
    a.deleteFriend(b);
    b.deleteFriend(a);
}

private void deleteFriend(Person a) {
    this.vrienden.remove(a);
}

public Collection<Person> getFriends() {
    return vrienden;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return this.role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

@NotNull(message = "{error.no.name}")
@Size(min = 2, message = "{error.invalid.namesize}")
public String getNaam() {
    return naam;
}

public void setNaam(String naam) {

    this.naam = naam;
}

@NotNull(message = "{error.no.surnaam}")
@Size(min = 2, message = "{error.invalid.surnamesize}")
public String getVoornaam() {
    return voornaam;
}

public void setVoornaam(String voornaam) {

    this.voornaam = voornaam;
}

@NotNull(message = "{error.no.email}")
@Email(message = "{error.invalid.email}")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@NotNull(message = "{error.no.status}")
@Size(min = 1, message = "{error.no.valid.status}")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {

    this.status = status;
}

@NotNull(message = "{error.no.username}")
@Size(min = 2, message = "{error.invalid.usernamesize}")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = Password.getSaltedHash(password);
}

public boolean isPasswordCorrect(String password) {
    boolean result = false;
        result = Password.check(password, this.password);      
    return result;
}

@NotNull(message = "{error.no.password}")
@Size(min = 2, message = "{error.invalid.usernamesize}")
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}



public void addPost(Post p) {
    if (p == null) {
        throw new DomainException("Post is null");
    }
    posts.add(p);
}

public void deletePost(Post p) {
    if (p == null) {
        throw new DomainException("Post is null");
    }
    posts.remove(p);
}

public Collection<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    hash = 59 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.username);
    return hash;
}

public void setHashedPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just made a wrapper class for Person. There is probably a better way... . 
but if you intrested this is the wrapper class:

```
public class WrapPerson {

private String naam;
private String voornaam;
private String email;
private String username;
private String status;

private Collection<String> vrienden;
private Collection<Post> posts;

public WrapPerson(Person person) {
    setEmail(person.getEmail());
    setNaam(person.getNaam());
    setPosts(person.getPosts());
    setStatus(person.getStatus());
    setUsername(person.getUsername());
    setVoornaam(person.getVoornaam());
    this.vrienden = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Person p : person.getFriends()) {
        this.vrienden.add(p.getUsername());
    }
}

public String getNaam() {
    return naam;
}

public void setNaam(String naam) {
    this.naam = naam;
}

public String getVoornaam() {
    return voornaam;
}

public void setVoornaam(String voornaam) {
    this.voornaam = voornaam;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Collection<String> getVrienden() {
    return vrienden;
}

public void setVrienden(Collection<String> vrienden) {
    this.vrienden = vrienden;
}

public Collection<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(Collection<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}

}
```

`